# Named query bindings in CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

CodeIgniter 3 [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.htm) , as well as in version 2, only mentions this kind of query bindings for building queries:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));`

Does anyone know if any kind of named query bindings are available though not documented?
I'm refering to something similar to

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = :id AND status = :status
```

...I expected some kind of improvement at this particular point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know this kind of query works with Symfony(as i know)

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = :id AND status = :status
```

so when you come to Codeigniter you have to follow this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'))
```

So query will be

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 3 AND status = 'live' AND author = 'Rick'
```

> > **So first method is not work with Codeigniter.**